# Sort array with rgb color on Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, colors, rgb

I am having an array in my javascript with rgb colors. Let's say it looks like this:

```
  colors = ['(133,10,22)', '(33,33,33)', '(255,255,255)', '(1,1,1)'];
```

How can I sort this array so as to get the lightest color first and the darkest last? So at the end my array to look like this for example:

```
 colors = ['(255,255,255)', '(133,10,22)', '(33,33,33)', '(1,1,1)'];
```

Is there any particular library someone needs to use, or it is like the biggest sum of r+g+b the lightest the color?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a very simple algorithm it can be just the sum. Each number represents the amount of light in each channel, so more light in total = brighter color.

Comment: @pawel So rgb(90, 90, 90) is brighter than rgb(255, 0, 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Juhuna pointed out, brightness is not the sum of the channels.

```
var colors = ['(133,10,22)', '(33,33,33)', '(255,255,255)', '(1,1,1)'];

function sumColor (str) {
  var rgb = str.replace(/[()]/g, "").split(",").map(Number);

  // Summing the channels does not calculate brightness, so this is incorrect:
  // return rgb[0] + rgb[1] + rgb[2];

  // To calculate relative luminance under sRGB and RGB colorspaces that use Rec. 709:
  return 0.2126*rgb[0] + 0.7152*rgb[1] + 0.0722*rgb[2];
}

colors.sort(function (a, b) {
  return sumColor(a) > sumColor(b);
}).reverse();
```

Comment: Brightness is not the sum of the channels.

Comment: tack I used this sum instead and then just sort. And I think works fine.