# Sort RGB color in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I would like to sort (from light to dark) the `mix` colorcode in this array (org. 1024 lines), but the output must also contain the corresponding c1 and c2 colorcode for later usage.

```
 var colors = [
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(255,249,225)', mix: 'rgb(255,252,240)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(205,205,205)', mix: 'rgb(230,230,230)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(171,163,144)', mix: 'rgb(213,209,199)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(28,28,28)', mix: 'rgb(141,141,141)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(97,9,17)', mix: 'rgb(176,132,136)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(170,11,39)', mix: 'rgb(212,133,147)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(206,116,108)', mix: 'rgb(230,185,181)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(243,218,221)', mix: 'rgb(249,236,238)' }
];
```

I tried to adjust [this example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960722/sort-array-with-rgb-color-on-javascript) but can't figure out how to get what I want. The prefered output can be the same array structure as above, so I can copy/paste it for futher usage.

Can someone come up with a possible solution?

UPDATE:
John Slegers gave my the best solution (beautiful from light to dark) with this code:

```
colors.sort(function(a, b) {
    var calculateLuminosity = function(rgb) {
        return rgb.replace(/[^[\d,]/g, "")
                  .split(",")
                  .map(Number)
                  .reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
    }
    var luminosity = {
        a : calculateLuminosity(a.mix),
        b : calculateLuminosity(b.mix),
    }
    if (luminosity.a === luminosity.b) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (luminosity.a > luminosity.b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(colors, null, '\t') + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you please add the expected output in the question?

Comment: Sorry, I will adjust the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :

```
colors.sort(function(a, b) {
    var calculateLuminosity = function(rgb) {
        return rgb.replace(/[^[\d,]/g, "")
                  .split(",")
                  .map(Number)
                  .reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
    };

    var luminosity = {
        a : calculateLuminosity(a.mix),
        b : calculateLuminosity(b.mix),
    };

    if (luminosity.a === luminosity.b) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (luminosity.a > luminosity.b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var colors = [
    { c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(255,249,225)', mix: 'rgb(255,252,240)' },
    { c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(205,205,205)', mix: 'rgb(230,230,230)' },
    { c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(171,163,144)', mix: 'rgb(213,209,199)' },
    { c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(28,28,28)', mix: 'rgb(141,141,141)' },
    { c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(97,9,17)', mix: 'rgb(176,132,136)' },
    { c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(170,11,39)', mix: 'rgb(212,133,147)' },
    { c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(206,116,108)', mix: 'rgb(230,185,181)' },
    { c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(243,218,221)', mix: 'rgb(249,236,238)' }
];

colors.sort(function(a, b) {
    var calculateLuminosity = function(rgb) {
        return rgb.replace(/[^[\d,]/g, "")
                  .split(",")
                  .map(Number)
                  .reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
    };

    var luminosity = {
        a : calculateLuminosity(a.mix),
        b : calculateLuminosity(b.mix),
    };

    if (luminosity.a === luminosity.b) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (luminosity.a > luminosity.b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(colors, null, '\t') + '</pre>';
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ka4zw9L3/1/))

Comment: I tried your first code on 1024 lines array and it gives the result from light to dark, beautiful. Your adjusted code gives a mix, light, darker, light, darker, darker. So, I use your first, before you adjusted it, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Harry : Great! I updated my answer again, based on your feedback :-)

Comment: No no, it's the code after this one and before your latest.

Comment: @Harry : This version?!

Comment: I will update my question with the code I mean so you can update your answer for my vote. (zag net dat je in de buurt woont :-))

Comment: @Harry : Ik zou verwachten dat die versie dezelfde output geeft als mijn laatste versie ( = https://jsfiddle.net/pgccomc4/1/)... maar bon, waarschijnlijk zie ik iets over 't hoofd. Ik heb mijn antwoord alvast opnieuw aangepast. Bedankt voor de feedback ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With a little modification of the [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960722/sort-array-with-rgb-color-on-javascript) (and correction of the sort callback function):

```js
function luminance(str) {
  // extract digits groups from strings like "rgb(255,255,255)"
  // and split into numbers:
  var rgb = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
  return 0.2126*rgb[0] + 0.7152*rgb[1] + 0.0722*rgb[2];
}

var colors = [
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(255,249,225)', mix: 'rgb(255,252,240)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(205,205,205)', mix: 'rgb(230,230,230)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(171,163,144)', mix: 'rgb(213,209,199)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(28,28,28)', mix: 'rgb(141,141,141)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(97,9,17)', mix: 'rgb(176,132,136)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(170,11,39)', mix: 'rgb(212,133,147)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(206,116,108)', mix: 'rgb(230,185,181)' },
{ c1: 'rgb(255,255,255)', c2: 'rgb(243,218,221)', mix: 'rgb(249,236,238)' }
];

colors.sort(function (a, b) {
  // this function expects an integer value, so subtract:
  return luminance(b.mix) - luminance(a.mix);
});

// Just for this snippet: display the result in readable form:
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(colors). replace(/},/g, '},\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will break apart the rgb, and calculate using the previous link the brightness from the RGB. I've added it as a property to the object.

```
for (var i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
  var rgb = colors[i].mix.match(/\d{3}/g)
  colors[i].brightness = 0.2126*rgb[0] + 0.7152*rgb[1] + 0.0722*rgb[2]
}
```

This sort method will then reorder the objects in the array depending on the brightness.

```
colors.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.brightness - b.brightness
})
```

The downside to this way is that you will have a 4th property on each object. However if you really wanted to you could loop through it and remove the properties.